# A regular expression to for set of all strings over { 0,1 } that end with " 1 " and has no substring " 00 " in it?

Tags: expression, automata

Like I said , I have this question related to Automata Theory..

What would be the possible solution ?
All I can think of is ( I know that might not be the solution..)

( 0.1*.1 ) + ( 1*.1 )

I know the " ( 0.1*.1 ) " part wont let me accept a string such as " 011101 " although it's a valid one , I need one more but only one 0 in it..
Is there any better solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you include a bunch of sequences that should or should not match?

Answer (score 1):

This is better answer - (01+1)*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:
    (01+1)(01+1)*

Comment: It can be shortened as `(01+1)+`

Comment: And in this way it requires two `1` to match. Maybe `(01+)+`?